# Class with Invocable method not visible in Profile.Apex Class Access

Tags: apex, invocable-method

I am getting an error with a class. Normal error telling me to allow access for this new Profile - probably not put the class in the profile Class Access... But when I go to look, the class is not available in neither list.

Error message:

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, We can't save this record because the “SMS Chatter Notification” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. Profile does not have access to: getemployeefromnumber
>   Error ID: 1119766178-30139 (477012206): []

Salesforce Admin profile has no issues. I've never done an Invocable Method so is this normal?

Adding class:

```
/*
 * SG Added this class : Gets the employee name and record from teh number back from Twilio. Must only return where contact.recordtype = Emploee
 * then we want to send a message to the person who is sending the messages.
*/

public class getEmployeefromNumber {

    @InvocableMethod(label='Get Employees' description='Get the employee who sent last message and posts a chatter message TO THAT USER.' category='TwilioSF__Message__c')
    public static void getEmployeefromNumber(List<id> pMessageIDs) {
        //get all message numbers
        list <TwilioSF__Message__c> paramMessages = [select id, TwilioSF__Body__c, OwnerId, TwilioSF__From_Number_Unformatted__c 
                                                      from TwilioSF__Message__c where id in : pMessageIDs];
        // set variables
        list<FeedItem> Posts = new list <FeedItem>();
        set<string> pMobileNumbers = new set<string>();
        set<id> empIDs = new set<id>();
        set<id> userIDs = new set<id>();
        map<string,string> EmpNames = new map<string,string>();
        map<string,id> MessageToUsers = new map<string,id>();
        map<string,string> fromNumbertoMessage = new map<string,string>();

        system.debug('\n _____> SEAN pMessageIDs = ' + pMessageIDs);
        system.debug('\n _____> SEAN paramMessages = ' + paramMessages);

        //get the numbers from the current messages
        for(TwilioSF__Message__c runMess :paramMessages){
          pMobileNumbers.add(runMess.TwilioSF__From_Number_Unformatted__c);
            fromNumbertoMessage.put(runMess.TwilioSF__From_Number_Unformatted__c, runMess.TwilioSF__Body__c);
        }
        system.debug('\n _____> SEAN pMobileNumbers = ' + pMobileNumbers);
        //get the employee from the number
        list <contact> allEmps = [select id, name, MobilePhone from contact where RecordTypeId = '0121I000000G0yDQAS' and MobilePhone in: pMobileNumbers];
        system.debug('\n _____> SEAN allEmps = ' + allEmps);

        // get a map of employee and their number and all employees who sent messages
        for(contact employee :  allEmps){
            EmpNames.put(employee.MobilePhone, employee.name);
            system.debug('\n SEAN EmpNames = ' + EmpNames);
            empIDs.add(employee.id);
            system.debug('\n SEAN empIDs = ' + empIDs);
        }

        // get the user who sent the last message to those employees above
        if(allEmps.size()>0){
            list <TwilioSF__Message__c> messages = [select id, TwilioSF__Body__c, OwnerId, TwilioSF__To_Number_Unformatted__c 
                                                      from TwilioSF__Message__c 
                                                      where TwilioSF__To_Number_Unformatted__c = :pMobileNumbers order by CreatedDate desc]; // age of message to limit the results?
            system.debug('\n SEAN messages = '+messages);

            // get a map of the numbers to the last users who sent a message and the list of all users who sent messages
            for(TwilioSF__Message__c message :  messages){
                if(!MessageToUsers.containsKey(message.TwilioSF__To_Number_Unformatted__c)){
                    System.debug('=======phonenumber====='+message.TwilioSF__To_Number_Unformatted__c);
                    System.debug('=======phonenumber====='+message.OwnerID);
                    MessageToUsers.put(message.TwilioSF__To_Number_Unformatted__c, message.OwnerID);
                }
                userIDs.add(message.OwnerID);
            }
            system.debug('\n SEAN MessageToUsers = '+MessageToUsers);
            system.debug('\n SEAN userIDs = '+userIDs);
            Map<ID, User> UserNames = new Map<ID, User>([SELECT Id, Name FROM User]);
            list<user> Users = [select Name from user where id in: userIDs];


            // loop through each number and send a post to the last person who sent a message
            // for each message number
            for(string fromNumber :pMobileNumbers){
                System.debug('======empnames====='+EmpNames.get(fromNumber));
                System.debug('======1====='+MessageToUsers.get(fromNumber));
                System.debug('======2====='+UserNames.get(MessageToUsers.get(fromNumber)));
                System.debug('======3====='+UserNames.get(MessageToUsers.get(fromNumber)).Name);
                System.debug('======4======='+fromNumbertoMessage.get(fromNumber));
              string body = EmpNames.get(fromNumber)+' responded to '+UserNames.get(MessageToUsers.get(fromNumber)).Name+'\'s outreach: ' + fromNumbertoMessage.get(fromNumber) ;// + message.TwilioSF__Body__c;
                Posts.add(postFeed(MessageToUsers.get(fromNumber), body));
            }
            //insert the post
            insert Posts;
        }
    }
    public static FeedItem postFeed(id pUserID, string pBody){
    FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
        post.ParentId = pUserID;
        post.Body = pBody;
        return post;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code, please?. :)

Comment: Keep in mind that, unless you're running your flow in "System mode", the user has to have access to the class being called... and the Admin user likely already has said access

Comment: Code added. The class isn't available in the list of Classes in the [Profile.Apex Class Access] area.

Comment: Are you sure? I'd ask you to check towards the bottom. Since your class starts with a lower case letter (and most classes start with upper case ones) you should find it towards the end of the list, since the sort is not case-insensitive IIRC.

Comment: OMG... REALLY??? dude. Thank you so much. @SebastianKessel

Comment: Lol. Glad this helped you. I'll add it as an answer so others can benefit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that, unless you're running your flow in "System mode", the user has to have access to the class being called... and the Admin user likely already has said access

I'd ask you to check towards the bottom. Since your class starts with a lower case letter (and most classes start with upper case ones) you should find it towards the end of the list, since the sort is not case-insensitive.

Comment: I'm  little old school. I always start my classes and variable with a lower case letter

Comment: For classes, old school has always been capitals. ;) I’m with you on variables, though